# Content from updated contact form 7 doesn't show on all pages

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, elementor

I have successfully published a contact form from **contact form 7** to a page with the short code, it worked perfectly, but after making some changes it turns out that the form is updated on the preview when connected to WordPress (wp-admin) but it is not showing when using the public link (it still shows the old content of the form).

The public link still have the old version of the form

Any idea why ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the website I found that it is not resetting the cache properly and changes worked after clearing the cache manually.
Problem comes from elementor and not contact form 7